# ssh and chroot followed by cd in shell

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

How to excute cd command after chroot to a remote node in shell script?

For ex:
I need this.

```
ssh remote-node "chroot-path cd command here; extra commands"
```

Without chroot it works fine, If I put the command list in another shell script and execute the shell script after chroot it seems to run okay.

But chroot seems to break cd?

Comment: What is this `chroot-path` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf %q` to have your local shell (which must be bash) give you correct quoting that works, and `bash -c` to explicitly invoke a remote shell compatible with that quoting (as `%q` can generate bash-only quoting with input strings that contain special characters) under your `chroot`.

```
cmd_str='cd /to/place; extra commands'
remote_command=( bash -c "$cmd_str" )
printf -v remote_command_str '%q ' "${remote_command[@]}"
ssh remote-node "chroot /path/here $remote_command_str"
```

The `bash -c` is necessary because `cd` is a shell construct, and `chroot` directly exec's its arguments (with no shell) by default.

The `printf %q` and correct (single-quote) quoting for `cmd_str` ensures that the command string is executed by the final shell (the `bash -c` invoked under the chroot), not your local shell, and not by the remote pre-chroot shell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by `chroot-path` you mean `chroot /some/root/path`.

`chroot` only takes a single command and `cd` isn't a command it is a shell built-in so that won't work.

Additionally only `cd command here` is being run (or attempted to) under the `chroot` setup. Everything after the `;` is running in the main shell.

A script is the easiest way to do what you want.